# Where can I find and check the source code of a token

Tags: ico

How can I find the source code for a token launched via an ICO? What is for instance the source code for this token and where do I find it: https://tokenmarket.net/blockchain/ethereum/assets/herocoin/

p.s. could be any other ico, I just want to be able to check before investing what they programmed into the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everyone will share the code to their smart contract, although it's an established practice as it shows transparency and makes people with some technical skills more willing to invest as they can make sure the code is not flawed or the developers deviced a way to make a run with the funds.

Having said that, using the ICO you asked about as reference, here's the steps I took to find the deployed contract:

1- Google "Herocoin github". The first result is the Github repository for HeroCoin and their ICO.

2- You can see that they added a message to their latest commit mentioning the address which the crowdsale contract was deployed to, which is: 0xe477292f1b3268687a29376116b0ed27a9c76170

3- Go to https://etherscan.io which allows you to search txs, addresses, tokens, etc.

4- Search the contract address and you will see all the details for the contract. ETH Balance, transactions, associated token, etc.

5- There's a tab called "Contract Source" where you will be able to see the deployed and verified code.

Again, they are not obliged to verify the code and the tokens you are looking for might not have it. It would surely raise a red flag as no one would be able to verify it's not a scam.

Answer (score 1):

There is literally a tab on etherscan that allows you to view that tokens contract lol. Just copy and paste the token contract into etherscan and click the contract tab. It is that easy.

Comment: Hi! I understand that this is an obvious answer to you, but may not be to those who are just string out and don't know about Etherscan. Please rephrase the answer a bit more respectfully (I would recommend taking out 'literally' and 'lol', among some others). You may also want to link to the Etherscan page, maybe include a screenshot showing where features are. Cheers!

Comment: shoutout @TheRenaissance